Novel; contains dinosaurs, geo-temporal anomaly, and societal collapse
The novel that I am trying to find a name for seems to be something that's fairly devoid of information on the internet, I will summarize as best as I can a few key points and hopefully that can jog someone else's memory:
The novel has a male main character and the main premise is that certain areas all over the world undergo some type of geo-temporal anomaly and are supplanted by identical areas, albeit from sometime in the jurrasic or triassic periods, complete with the corresponding flora and fauna.
The story revolves around this main characters attempts to survive the following societal collapse and hostilities from the large predatory animals now in the modern time period.
Here are the main plot points I am able to recall:

MC uses gold/jewelry to buy large rifle, then later kills a tyrannosaur*?
MC takes care of an old woman holed up in her apartment for a while until they end up dying.
A scene of a herd of hadrosaurs that the MC had befriended while in the aforementioned half city/cretaceous jungle are shot at by a group of people and the main character has a bittersweet moment at the cruelty of such actions.

I cannot really recall anything else that would help find the book but if anyone has any ideas, It would be greatly appreciated! This has been driving me nuts for a while.

Any idea when you read it? hen you think it was published?

Some searching turns up Footprints of Thunder (1995) by James F. David as the most likely possibility.
The blurb discusses how chunks of the present-day world are replaced by chunks of the world from the time of the dinosaurs:

When a freak natural phenomenon dissolves the boundaries between yesterday and today, the world is transformed into a patchwork mixture of the present and the distant past. Entire cities are replaced by primeval forests. Prehistoric monsters stalk modern city streets, hunting for human prey.
While ordinary men and women struggle to survive in this strange new world, the president and his advisers search for a way to undo the catastrophe. But the solution may be more devastating than the dinosaurs....

There are reviews on the book's Goodreads page that indicate the time mix-up was an apocalyptic event for modern society.

The protagonist does buy a rifle with gold coins:

He tried the first sporting goods store again. The owner was belligerent until Colter held out his hand with two gold coins. The owner looked over the coins and even bit one to make sure they were real. Then the negotiation started. While interested, the dealer wouldn't sell Colter the rifle he wanted for only two of the coins. Colter mournfully told the man he had only four coins and a family back in Ashland and wasn't sure he could go back without protection. [...]
Colter held his ground and the negotiation continued. Colter didn't want to give him four gold pieces— but there was no way to make change. Colter now understood why pirate treasure was often pieces of eight—breaking his gold coins into eighths would make the negotiation simpler. Finally, Colter thanked the man and said he'd try the shop down the street. That's where he got the deal he wanted—the rifle, three spare eight-round clips, and three boxes of ammunition for three gold coins. Then Colter went looking for supplies.

A different set of characters kill a tyrannosaur a bit earlier in the book, but I can't find the relevant page to grab a quote.
